# Adding 'mean', 'min' or 'percentiles' to Spring Boot 2 metrics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am using the new **MicroMeter** metrics in **Spring Boot 2** version `2.0.0-RELEASE`.

When publishing metrics over the `/actuator/metrics/{metric.name}` endpoint, i get the following:

For a `DistributionSummary` :

```
"name": "sources.ingestion.rate",
    "measurements": [
        {
           "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL",
            "value": 72169.44162067816
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 17870.68010661754
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": []
}
```

For a `Timer` :

```
{
    "name": "sources.ingestion",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 65.700878648
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 22.661545322
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": []
}
```

Is it possible to enrich the measurements to **add measures** like *mean*, *min*, or *percentiles* ?

For percentiles i tried using `.publishPercentiles(0.5, 0.95)`, but that doesn't reflect on the actuator endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After discussions on Github, this is not currently implemented in Micrometer.
More details directly on the Github Issues:

- https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/488#issuecomment-373249656
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12433
- https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/457

Comment: Thanks for investigation. I miss this functionality as well.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can implement percentiles-histogram like this:

```
management:
  metrics:
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        http.server.requests: true
```

Then you can see histogram data in `/actuator/prometheus`, but can not see in `/metrics`. Because it will generate only for endpoint which supports histogram.

Also have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties).